# How to play local video in ionic 3.7 on windows 8 mobile?

Tags: html, angular, video, ionic-framework, windows-mobile

The project was migrated to electron for better windows 8 mobile compatibility (everything breaks otherwise).
I've seen workarounds and cordova video players, but for android and iOS only.
Is there another cross-platform way of playing a local video other than the html5 way?

```
  <div class="video-container">
    <video width="900px" height="440px" controls autoplay>
      <source src="../../assets/videos/my-video.mp4"/>
    </video>
  </div>
```